# Java getPeerCertificates() performance

Tags: java, ssl

I'm have a server application, and there is a single line

```
Certificate[] certs = sslSocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
```

that require about 5 seconds to complete.
Is there a way to get work it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no I/O has been done on the socket, getSession() initiates the SSL handshake, which can take that long. You are communicating with the peer. It will work faster if I/O has already been done on the socket, but then of course the cost just shifts to the first I/O call.

Comment: There 5Mbit line between server and client... Why handshake take so long time? Or... you mean latency... Do i'm need reduce latency between this hosts? Or any other sugg.?

Comment: Oh my... It's not really right answer but give me right direction. Actually this is not java related problem but SSL in general. This happens cause slow host resolution problem. I'm temporary add host to my hosts file and handshake shortens from 5 seconds to 0.33 sec.